# Angular Treemap passing data from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

There is a d3 treemap code at this link -

http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/h0q6xb45/1/

Now the data in this is static, i.e. its in a scope in controller but not loaded from anywhere. So I coded one service-

```
app.service('grabdata', function($http){
var data = [];
$http.get('someApi').then(function success(response){
var company = [];
var wtdCagr = [];
var children = [];
for(var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++){
  company.push(response.data[i].companies);
  wtdCagr.push(response.data[i].wtdcagr);
  children.push({name:response.data[i].companies, value: 3241});
}
  data.push({name:"flare", children:children});
});
return {
getData: function(){
  return data[0];
   }
  };
});
```

and I have the controller set up-

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http','grabdata', function($scope, $http, grabdata) {
  $scope.$watch(grabdata.getData, function(change){
  $scope.data = change;
  }, true);
}]);
```

And I edited the directive a bit-

```
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  scope: {data: '='},

  link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(scope.data, function(newValue){
      console.log(newValue);
      var root = scope.data;

    });
   var root = scope.data;
```

But I get this error on my console-

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

That means data does not go in the directive, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me rewrite few things for you so you can try and let me know if it is ok:

```
 //service    
 app.service('grabdata', function($http, $q){
  var data = [];
  return({
     getData:getData
  });

 function getData(){
   var defer = $q.defer();
   $http.get('someApi').then(function success(response){
   var company = [];
   var wtdCagr = [];
   var children = [];
   for(var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++){
     company.push(response.data[i].companies);
     wtdCagr.push(response.data[i].wtdcagr);
     children.push({name:response.data[i].companies, value: 3241});
   }
   data.push({name:"flare", children:children});
   defer.resolve(data[0]);
   return defer.promise;
 }
});



//controller
 app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http','grabdata', function($scope, $http, grabdata) {
    var $scope.data = [];
    grabdata.getData().then(function(response){
        $scope.data = response;
    });
    $scope.$watch($scope.data, function(newData,oldData){
       if(newData !== oldData){//workout some logic since this is array or object ??
           $scope.data = newData;
       }
    }, true);

 }]);
```

$http service call is async and you need to return promise to the party that is interested in the data, and when the promise is resolved you will get your data. I didn't go into why your object length is undefined, just make sure `response.data` is present. I would suggest reading about async data handling, your life will be easier. You can also return $http.get('/someapi') and handle data in controller if thats the way you want to do it

Comment: Now I'm getting this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` pointing towards `grabdata.getData()..` function @vodich

Comment: looks like your grabdata service is not found. Make sure you load it

Comment: grabdata is undefined. so the file containing the service is not loaded, angular cant find the service